# How do I run speech recognizer before all other tasks in Java, in such a way that only if the output contains begin, the program continues

Tags: java, inheritance, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a login page and a sign up page in my program.
I want to run it only if the user says begin. 
These pages are called in the main method of my class, and I have a speech recognizer class.
I want the program to continue only when String `output.contains("begin") == true`

I tried putting the `Class.main(args)` in my `if(output.contains("begin") == true))` case, there was an unhandled exception, and when i surrounded that section with try and catch, it didn't work.

I was told that Inheriting and implementing the classes from my API will work, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

```
final Microphone mic = new Microphone(FLACFileWriter.FLAC);
GSpeechDuplex duplex = new GSpeechDuplex("AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw");            
duplex.setLanguage("en");
duplex.addResponseListener(new GSpeechResponseListener() {
    String old_text = "";

    public void onResponse(GoogleResponse gr) {
        String output = gr.getResponse();
        if (gr.getResponse() == null) {
            this.old_text = response.getText();
            if (this.old_text.contains("(")) {
                this.old_text = this.old_text.substring(0, 
                this.old_text.indexOf('('));
            }                
            System.out.println("Paragraph Line Added");
            this.old_text = ( response.getText() + "\n" );
            this.old_text = this.old_text.replace(")", "").replace("( ", "");                
            response.setText(this.old_text);

        }
        if (output.contains("(")) {
            output = output.substring(0, output.indexOf('('));
        }
        if (!gr.getOtherPossibleResponses().isEmpty()) {
            output = output + " (" + (String) 
            gr.getOtherPossibleResponses().get(0) + ")";
        }
        response.setText("");
        response.append(this.old_text);
        response.append(output);

        System.out.println(output);

        if(output.contains("begin") == true){
            duplex.stopSpeechRecognition();
            mic.close();
            Trying_Different_Languages t = new Trying_Different_Languages();
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

Expect The program to begin when i say begin but
It it doesn't begin when I say begin.
The try and catch statements just help in error free compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a program there should exist only 1 `public static void main(String[] args)` method. That is the indicator which tells you there starts the program.

Instead of calling the main method you should add a different method which do the stuff you want at a specific point.

So in detail it can look like that:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void someMethodName() {
        //some stuff you want to execute
    }
}
```

So and where you want to execute the code:

```
...
SomeClass.someMethodName(); //executes the stuff you want.
```

In this case it would work if you create different methods which do exactly that you need to do at a specific point.